# How to restore SQL data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a backup table with 15,000 rows. The data was directly copied from a main table. I need to perform an UPDATE statement on the main table, using the data from the backup table. Both tables are identical in structure and use a unique primary key called ID.

How do I loop through the backup table, find the matching record for each row in the main table, and then replace each record in main table with the matching record in the backup table?

Thanks

EDIT:

Proposed Solution based on Sean Lange's comment:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.col1 = b.col1
, a.col2 = b.col2

FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JOIN update to accomplish this.  Assuming they have matching primary key ID's, it should be quick and painless.

```
UPDATE table1
SET a.col1 = b.col2
, a.col2 = b.col2

FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: This looks good. I will test it tonight and provide feedback.

Comment: This is good but you need to update the alias instead of the table name. There are times that it will get the rows confused.

Comment: thanks dfundako. Sean Lange, did you mean to make it like my proposed solution above?